# To recall (a message)

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I just got an english message like this:

> Mr. Miller would like to recall the message, "<subject-of-email>"

Now I searched for translations of "recall", a word I only know from [Hoodwinked!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoodwinked!).

I understand that recall can mean that the message is revoked/removed/made undone, or that it can mean that he enquires me to answer to that mail.

These are kind of diametrically opposites, but which one is it?

Comment: There's the possibility he is inviting you to remember it; though that strictly would need ..'would like you to recall…' or even that he is remembering it himself. Both would need more context to decide. The sentence as it stands would not make me think he wanted to 'cancel the previous message'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Mr miller would like to recall (cancel) the message". He doesn't want you to answer it; he wants you to treat it as cancelled.

"Recall" also means to cancel. Please refer to The Free Dictionary.

Comment: If you decide to treat it as cancelled, then you might as well delete the cancelled message forever, since the original intention is that the message might contain confidential information and was sent unintentionally. Double check it with the sender!

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old answered question, but I feel that I should provide a more detailed answer.

**What does it mean?**

> Mr. Miller would like to recall the message, "<subject-of-email>"

The message that you received is most likely the result of recipient using the 'recall' feature provided by Microsoft Outlook. How do I know this? Well this matches the format of the default message sent, if the recall feature doesn't work as planned.

To get straight to the point, the recipient is trying to revoke an email which they previously sent to you. Essentially, they want you to ignore or disregard the email you received with the specified subject.

However, this is not always the case usually if someone wanted you to ignore their email, then they would be more specific; rather than just leaving you with an email stating that they would like to recall their message.

As I mentioned, this email is automatically sent when the 'recall' feature in Microsoft Outlook is not able to revoke the sent email. The user of this feature may have accidentally recalled their email or have a different intention such as preventing only one of their recipients from receiving their email.

**Why?**

There are many reasons, why someone would like to recall their email.

*Have you ever had that moment where you sent an email and then you realized you made mistakes?*

Mistakes can include:

- Sending your email to unintended recipients
- Adding the wrong attachment
- Information you sent is incorrect

If you were in that situation, then you probably want to prevent your email from reaching your recipients.

Well luckily, some email clients such as Microsoft Outlook provide the functionality to allow the sender to 'recall' their message. In other words, they can 'take back' the email that they have sent and make it so that the email is deleted from the recipient's inbox if unread.

However, there are cases where this feature will not work as described in most cases, such as if you are using an entirely different email client to the recipient or if the email is already read. If this feature cannot delete the email from the recipient's inbox then the following message would be sent to them:

> "<recipient-name>" would like to recall the message, "<subject-of-email>"

If you would like to know more about this feature then check out this website link:
[How to recall an email – and why you shouldn’t do it!](http://www.businessproductivity.com/how-to-recall-an-email-and-why-you-shouldnt-do-it/)